# how to show download process while downloading a image

Tags: android, android-progressbar

i am working on wallpaper app in which i am downloading image, but now i want to show download process  while downloading a image.

**what i want is: see this screenshot:**  http://www.techfeb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/download-facebook-photos-on-android-smartphone-2.jpg

this is my code:

**Utils.java**

```
package info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.util;

import info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Utils {
    private String TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context _context;
    private PrefManager pref;   

    // constructor
    public Utils(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = new PrefManager(_context);
    }

    /*
     * getting screen width
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
            // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }

    public void saveImageToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String dirname = "/Amazing Wallpapers/";

        File myDir = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + dirname);

        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);

        String fname = "Wallpaper-" +n+".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#",
                            "\"" + pref.getGalleryName() + "\""),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Wallpaper saved to:" + file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context);

            wm.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_wallpaper_set_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**FullScreenActivity.java**

```
package info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers;

import info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.picasa.model.Wallpaper;
import info.androidhive.awesomewallpapers.util.Utils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = FullScreenViewActivity.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG_SEL_IMAGE = "selectedImage";
    private Wallpaper selectedPhoto;
    private ImageView fullImageView;
    private LinearLayout llSetWallpaper, llDownloadWallpaper;
    private Utils utils;
    private ProgressBar pbLoader;

    // Picasa JSON response node keys
    private static final String TAG_ENTRY = "entry",
            TAG_MEDIA_GROUP = "media$group",
            TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT = "media$content", TAG_IMG_URL = "url",
            TAG_IMG_WIDTH = "width", TAG_IMG_HEIGHT = "height";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_image);

        fullImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFullscreen);
        llSetWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSetWallpaper);
        llDownloadWallpaper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llDownloadWallpaper);
        pbLoader = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoader);

        // hide the action bar in fullscreen mode
        getActionBar().hide();

        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        // layout click listeners
        llSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);

        // setting layout buttons alpha/opacity
        llSetWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);
        llDownloadWallpaper.getBackground().setAlpha(70);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        selectedPhoto = (Wallpaper) i.getSerializableExtra(TAG_SEL_IMAGE);

        // check for selected photo null
        if (selectedPhoto != null) {

            // fetch photo full resolution image by making another json request
            fetchFullResolutionImage();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching image fullresolution json
     * */
    private void fetchFullResolutionImage() {
        String url = selectedPhoto.getPhotoJson();

        // show loader before making request
        pbLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        llSetWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llDownloadWallpaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // volley's json obj request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Image full resolution json: "
                                        + response.toString());
                        try {
                            // Parsing the json response
                            JSONObject entry = response
                                    .getJSONObject(TAG_ENTRY);

                            JSONArray mediacontentArry = entry.getJSONObject(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_GROUP).getJSONArray(
                                    TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT);

                            JSONObject mediaObj = (JSONObject) mediacontentArry
                                    .get(0);

                            String fullResolutionUrl = mediaObj
                                    .getString(TAG_IMG_URL);

                            // image full resolution widht and height
                            final int width = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_WIDTH);
                            final int height = mediaObj.getInt(TAG_IMG_HEIGHT);

                            Log.d(TAG, "Full resolution image. url: "
                                    + fullResolutionUrl + ", w: " + width
                                    + ", h: " + height);

                            ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController
                                    .getInstance().getImageLoader();

                            // We download image into ImageView instead of
                            // NetworkImageView to have callback methods
                            // Currently NetworkImageView doesn't have callback
                            // methods

                            imageLoader.get(fullResolutionUrl,
                                    new ImageListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(
                                                VolleyError arg0) {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(
                                                ImageContainer response,
                                                boolean arg1) {
                                            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                                                // load bitmap into imageview
                                                fullImageView
                                                        .setImageBitmap(response
                                                                .getBitmap());
                                                adjustImageAspect(width, height);

                                                // hide loader and show set &
                                                // download buttons
                                                pbLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                llSetWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                llDownloadWallpaper
                                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    getString(R.string.msg_unknown_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // unable to fetch wallpapers
                        // either google username is wrong or
                        // devices doesn't have internet connection
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                getString(R.string.msg_wall_fetch_error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

        // Remove the url from cache
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

        // Disable the cache for this url, so that it always fetches updated
        // json
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Adjusting the image aspect ration to scroll horizontally, Image height
     * will be screen height, width will be calculated respected to height
     * */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
            return;

        int sHeight = 0;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            sHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            sHeight = display.getHeight();
        }

        int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
                / (double) bHeight);
        params.width = new_width;
        params.height = sHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "Fullscreen image new dimensions: w = " + new_width
                + ", h = " + sHeight);

        fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    /**
     * View click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) fullImageView.getDrawable())
                .getBitmap();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        // button Download Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llDownloadWallpaper:
            utils.saveImageToSDCard(bitmap);
            break;
        // button Set As Wallpaper tapped
        case R.id.llSetWallpaper:
            utils.setAsWallpaper(bitmap);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: did u tried asynctask?

Comment: actually i don't know how so i am asking :(

Comment: ok google it once asynctask in android

Comment: i did but not understanding, can you give me a sample code adjusted with my code

Comment: try below answer and if not undertsood then i can help u

Comment: actually i am not understanding where and how do i implement, see full code here i used this same code in my app: `http://www.androidhive.info/2014/08/android-building-free-wallpapers-app-part-1/`

Comment: ohh lets dicuss on chat?

Comment: not enough reputation to chat

Answer (score 0):

A very good toturial to do so here..

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-download-image-from-url/\
A snippet of the code from the site is below:

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

        String imageURL = URL[0];

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // Set the bitmap into ImageView
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
        // Close progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProgressDialog within the onCreate method.

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

You can then add other attributes like a message and so on like this:

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
```

You can also add listeners like this:

```
mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Do stuff on Cancel
    }
});
```

Check this link:

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)